# TypeScript Type Inference For Simple Function Combination

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings, ramda.js

I'm having a tough time with what I would think should be relatively simple. I can't get the types to comes through in trying to do a simple combination of a couple functions. Is there a way to tell TS to figure out the type inference without having to explicitly put something?

```
import { pipe, map } from 'ramda'

type TODO = unkown

export const mapP = (xf: TODO) => (data: TODO) =>
  pipe(
    map(xf),
    x => Promise.all(x),
  )(data)
```

I really just want to let `map` dictate the types for the function and not have to retype them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { pipe, map } from 'ramda'

export const mapP = <T,R>(xf: (value:T) => Promise<R>|R) => (data: T[]): Promise<R[]> =>
  pipe(
    map(xf),
    x => Promise.all(x),
  )(data)
```

Does this require any explanantions?

Comment: Yeah, that worked great. Felt like I tried that but maybe was missing some aspect of it. Thanks!